# quickFix subgroup parsing failed

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Hi I am not able to get `NoPartyIds(443)` group inside my `NoSides` group while capturing `TradeCaptureReport`

```
Iterator<Integer> groupIterator= message.groupKeyIterator();

    while (groupIterator.hasNext()) {
        int num = groupIterator.next();
        List<Group> groups = message.getGroups(num);
        log.info("Group Number:"+num+", Groups:"+groups);
        for (Group groupInLoop : groups) {
            quickfix.fix50sp2.TradeCaptureReport.NoSides noSidesGroup = new quickfix.fix50sp2.TradeCaptureReport.NoSides();
            noSidesGroup.setFields(groupInLoop);
            noSidesGroup.get(side);
            noSidesGroup.get(account);
            NoPartyIDs noPartyIDs = new NoPartyIDs();
            noSidesGroup.get(noPartyIDs);
            log.info("side:"+side+", account:"+account+", noPartyIDs:"+noPartyIDs);

            Iterator<Integer> noPartyIDsGroupIterator= noSidesGroup.groupKeyIterator();
            log.info("noSidesGroup.groupKeyIterator(): "+noSidesGroup.groupKeyIterator());
            log.info("noSidesGroup: "+noSidesGroup.toString()+", noSidesGroup.getGroups(453):"+noSidesGroup.getGroups(453));

            log.info("noPartyIDsGroupIterator:"+noPartyIDsGroupIterator);
            while (noPartyIDsGroupIterator.hasNext()) {


                int noPartyIDsNum = noPartyIDsGroupIterator.next();
                List<Group> noPartyIDsGroups = noSidesGroup.getGroups(noPartyIDsNum);
                log.info("Group Number:"+noPartyIDsNum+", Groups:"+noPartyIDsGroups);
                for (Group noPartyIDsGroupInLoop : noPartyIDsGroups) {
                    quickfix.fix50sp2.TradeCaptureReport.NoSides.NoPartyIDs partyIdGroup = new quickfix.fix50sp2.TradeCaptureReport.NoSides.NoPartyIDs();
                    partyIdGroup.setFields(noPartyIDsGroupInLoop);
                    partyIdGroup.get(partyId);
                    partyIdGroup.get(partyRole);
                    log.info("partyId:"+partyId+", partyRole:"+partyRole);
                }
            }


        }
```

My `noPartyIDsGroupIterator.hasNext()` returns empty and has nothing but in my message it has fields.

Data dictioanry looks like :

```
<message msgcat='app' msgtype='AE' name='TradeCaptureReport'>
  <field name='TradeReportID' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeID' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeReportTransType' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeReportType' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeRequestID' required='N'/>
  <field name='TrdType' required='N'/>
  <field name='ExecType' required='N'/>
  <field name='LastRptRequested' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeReportRefID' required='N'/>
  <field name='TrdMatchID' required='N'/>
  <field name='ExecID' required='N'/>
  <field name='SecondaryExecID' required='N'/>
  <field name='ExecRestatementReason' required='N'/>
  <field name='PreviouslyReported' required='N'/>
  <field name='Symbol' required='N'/>
  <field name='SecurityID' required='N'/>
  <field name='SecurityIDSource' required='N'/>
  <field name='LastQty' required='N'/>
  <field name='LastPx' required='N'/>
  <field name='Currency' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeDate' required='N'/>
  <field name='AvgPx' required='N'/>
  <field name='TransactTime' required='N'/>
  <field name='CopyMsgIndicator' required='N'/>
  <component name='TrdCapRptSideGrp' required='N'/>
  <component name='TrdInstrmtLegGrp' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradingProtectionLimit' required='N'/>
  <field name='TradeEventDecription' required='N'/>
</message>
<component name='TrdCapRptSideGrp'>
  <group name='NoSides' required='N'>
    <field name='Side' required='N'/>
    <field name='SideLastQty' required='N'/>
    <field name='SideTradeReportID' required='N'/>
    <field name='SideCurrency' required='N'/>
    <!--<component name='NoPartyIDsGrp' required='N'/>-->
    <group name='NoPartyIDs' required='N'>
      <field name='PartyID' required='N'/>
      <field name='PartyIDSource' required='N'/>
      <field name='PartyRole' required='N'/>
    </group>
    <field name='Account' required='N'/>
    <field name='Text' required='N'/>
    <field name='OrderID' required='N'/>
    <field name='ClOrdID' required='N'/>
    <field name='RefOrdIDReason' required='N'/>
    <field name='OrdType' required='N'/>
    <field name='Price' required='N'/>
    <field name='StopPx' required='N'/>
    <field name='ExecInst' required='N'/>
    <field name='OrdStatus' required='N'/>
    <field name='OrderQty' required='N'/>
    <field name='LeavesQty' required='N'/>
    <field name='CumQty' required='N'/>
    <field name='TimeInForce' required='N'/>
    <field name='ExpireDate' required='N'/>
    <field name='ExpireTime' required='N'/>
  </group>
</component>
```

Also for `noPartyIDs` field inside `noSidesGroup` it gives count of 5, but cannot access elements inside this noPartyIDsgroup.

Comment: Are these group iterators the recommended way of doing it in QF/j now?  I suspect that at some point one of them is not working like you think it is.  I suggest trying an alternate implementation that looks more like the [docs](https://quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.0.0//usage/repeating_groups.html) and does not use the iterators.

Comment: yes I tried `message.getGroup(num, noSidesGroup)` but it was giving me an exception of `Field not found: 552` ,  where `num` is my number of groups in message. But if I do `message.getGroup(1, noSidesGroup)` it works good. since i wanted to iterate through groups and get data ,I tried this way.

Comment: Also can you help me with regenerating QF/j with my DD? I downloaded quickfix from [here](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj) and in `quickfixj-master\quickfixj-messages\quickfixj-messages-fixt11\src\main\resources` changed `FIXT11.xml` to my updated one, and tried running command `mvn package`, but it gives error that - `LegSecurityID` not found. I think m not doing it right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to resolve by using `groupInLoop` as iterator for `noPartyIds` group.

```
Iterator<Integer> noPartyIDsGroupIterator= groupInLoop.groupKeyIterator();
```